# How to prove with and without using Einstein summation method?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, vectors, commutator

To proof :
[**A**.**L**,**B**.**L**] = i(**A**x**B**).**L**

Where two vectors **A** & **B** commute with each other and with **L** also.
**L** is angular momentum operator

[image: I have expended the expression upto some extent]

Comment: Hi Amit.  Rather than posting images of text and equations, please type them out so they can be properly indexed by search engines and interpreted for visually impaired users.  For formulae you can use MathJax, a tutorial for which can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: $[\vec a,\vec b]=0$ means $[a_i,b_j]=0$.

Comment: How is it possible because your first expression suggests that the (summation of the (dot product A.B - dot product B.A)= 0)

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, if the $a_i$ and $b_j$ are operators, then you're right, you cannot factor out
$$
\sum_{i,j}\left(a_iL_iL_jb_j-b_jL_jL_ia_i\right)
=
\sum_{i,j}a_ib_j(L_iL_j-L_jL_i).
$$
However, you're explicitly given $[\vec a,\vec b]=[\vec a,\vec L]=[\vec b,\vec L]=0$, i.e., every component of $\vec a$ commutes with every component of $\vec L$ and $\vec b$ (and vice versa), so the factorization *is* allowed by the premises.

Comment: No , It doesn't mean that every component of a will commute with every component of b and l
Plz check the image attached

Answer (score -2):

The terms $a_i$ and $b_i$ are just numbers. Your operators are $L_i$ and $L_j$.

Comment: A and B can be Vector fields and Operators also

Comment: Are you sure it is not implied that $\mathbf{A}=\left(a_{1}\mathbb{I},a_{2}\mathbb{I},a_{3}\mathbb{I}\right)$

Comment: Actually it is not mentioned in the original question

Comment: I think that what I said is a reasonable assumption, otherwise you would need further details. Moreover, this is the only case in which you can derive the result in your book. If you want you can also brute force the problem, and write all comutators.

Comment: Thank you , I am satisfied

Comment: The premises in the OP specify $[\vec a,\vec b]=0$, which would be trivially true if the $a_i$ and $b_i$ were just numbers.

Comment: That is a good observation. Moreover, the result OP presented will not be true in general.

Comment: How would one go about writing all possible a's and b's that commute with L?